# Invoking repo actions from multi-select

Tags: alfresco

I've created an UI action using various guides (include Jeff Potts really great ones) successfully and it function exactly as expected - but I want to add that action to the multi-select tool as well. It has been really difficult finding much documentation.

Some things I've tried:

Tried to find out if there was an applicable actionGroup - which there doesn't seem to be.

Tried adding the multi-select tags to my share-config-custom.xml to define the item - it shows up, but I obviously can't seem to use the action ID to reference that action.

My next step was to try and create a js file with a registerAction function in it, which I am able to do and have it run (I can see the console.log dump) but I don't really have any idea how I would go about invoking my repo action from there).

How can I complete this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already function exist for invoking the repository custom action.This function is defined inside below file.

share-war\components\documentlibrary\actions.js

You can take reference of below code for invoking the repository action.

```
onActionSimpleRepoAction: function dlA_onActionSimpleRepoAction(record, owner)
      {
         //ACE-2470 : Clone: Clicking multiple times the simple Workflow approval menu item gives unexpected results.
         if (owner.title.indexOf("_deactivated") == -1)
         {
         // Get action params
         var params = this.getAction(record, owner).params,
            displayName = record.displayName,
            namedParams = ["function", "action", "success", "successMessage", "failure", "failureMessage", "async"],
            repoActionParams = {};

         for (var name in params)
         {
            if (params.hasOwnProperty(name) && !Alfresco.util.arrayContains(namedParams, name))
            {
               repoActionParams[name] = params[name];
            }
         }

         //Deactivate action
         var ownerTitle = owner.title;
         owner.title = owner.title + "_deactivated";

         var async = params.async ? "async=" + params.async : null;

         // Prepare genericAction config
         var config =
         {
            success:
            {
               event:
               {
                  name: "metadataRefresh",
                  obj: record
               }
            },
            failure:
            {
               message: this.msg(params.failureMessage, displayName),
               fn: function showAction()
               {
                  owner.title = ownerTitle;
               },
               scope: this
            },
            webscript:
            {
               method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.POST,
               stem: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + "api/",
               name: "actionQueue",
               queryString: async
            },
            config:
            {
               requestContentType: Alfresco.util.Ajax.JSON,
               dataObj:
               {
                  actionedUponNode: record.nodeRef,
                  actionDefinitionName: params.action,
                  parameterValues: repoActionParams
               }
            }
         };

         // Add configured success callbacks and messages if provided
         if (YAHOO.lang.isFunction(this[params.success]))
         {
            config.success.callback =
            {
               fn: this[params.success],
               obj: record,
               scope: this
            };
         }
         if (params.successMessage)
         {
            config.success.message = this.msg(params.successMessage, displayName);
         }

         // Acd configured failure callback and message if provided
         if (YAHOO.lang.isFunction(this[params.failure]))
         {
            config.failure.callback =
            {
               fn: this[params.failure],
               obj: record,
               scope: this
            };
         }
         if (params.failureMessage)
         {
            config.failure.message = this.msg(params.failureMessage, displayName);
         }

         // Execute the repo action
         this.modules.actions.genericAction(config);
         }
      },
```